Microsoft Access: WHERE statement using AND & OR only responding to one condition
I have a simple query to search records using three fields. Users can do this via a form that has a text box for each of those three fields.
Condition 1: if textbox1 entry is an exact match to field A
Condition 2: OR if textbox2 entry is like a value in field B
Condition 3: OR if textbox 3 entry is like a value in field C
User can search by any of those criteria.
I'm running into two scenarios:

it will either match ONLY by condition 1 and even if it doesn't have a match, it won't produce a result through conditions 2 and 3.
it will produce results in either conditions 2 and 3, correctly using the like statements and when I try condition 1, even though it should be a clear cut result, it pulls every record

I've altered the SQL to make sure the conditions are running in the proper order, but I literally don't see anything wrong with my code. I've tried separating them, i.e., isolated condition 1 and it works. Then isolating conditions 2 and 3, it works.
The code is as follows:
SELECT Index.[Rec No], Index.[Type of Plan], Index.[Index Code], Index.Project, Index.Year, Index.Consultant, Index.[Needs Reassigned?], Index.[Label Needed], Index.[Scan Status], Index.Notes
FROM [Index]
WHERE 
    (Index.[Rec No])=[Forms]![Edit Record]![Rec No])
    ) 
    OR (
    (Index.[Index Code]) Like ("*" & [Forms]![Edit Record]![Index Code] & "*")
    ) 
    AND 
    (Index.Project) Like ("*" & [Forms]![Edit Record]![Project] & "*")
    )
ORDER BY Index.[Rec No], Index.[Index Code];

Do you see something wrong that would make the first condition not work??
UPDATE: workaround achieved by having two separate queries. One for the exact match and one for the similar matches. On the user form, the command button will run the exact match query if anything is entered, else it will run the similar match query. Since I couldn't actually figure out what I was doing wrong

Use of parenthesis is important, but it's very use is also not helpful... All but one set of parentheses are pointless if your WHERE.

Don't try to describe the problematic behaviour, show us ; read [mre] for more details...

@DaleK wasn't sure the appropriate tags and thought the intent of tags was to reach the right groups. My apologies

@MatBailie gotcha. My apologies. Thanks for the info

@ThomA Sorry about that. I originally entered the criteria in design view, then went into SQL and just left it as access created it. I cleared them out as suggested by a comment below. Unfortunately, I switched to design view and back to SQL again and it reverts it back to what I pasted. I will note for future posts though and have it formatted for the post itself at least!

@DaleK corrected. thanks

The first thing we want to do is use white space to expand the WHERE clause in a readable way. No one could decipher that mess as written:
WHERE 
    (
        ( (Index.[Rec No])=[Forms]![Edit Record]![Rec No] )
    )
    OR 
    (
            ( (Index.[Index Code]) Like ("*" & [Forms]![Edit Record]![Index Code] & "*") ) 
        AND ( (Index.Project) Like ("*" & [Forms]![Edit Record]![Project] & "*") )
    )

Then we can clean out some of the excessive parentheses:
WHERE 
    (
         Index.[Rec No] = [Forms]![Edit Record]![Rec No] 
    )
    OR 
    (
             Index.[Index Code] Like ("*" & [Forms]![Edit Record]![Index Code] & "*")  
        AND  Index.Project Like ("*" & [Forms]![Edit Record]![Project] & "*")
    )

And now the logic should be MUCH easier to follow... possibly such that the error is clear.

Excessive parantesis is one of those access things

Sorry about that. I originally entered the criteria in design view, then went into SQL and just left it as access created it. I cleared them out as suggested. Still can't see the error but definitely easier to read so thanks for the tip! (LOL I changed it and went back in and it wiped all the better formatting away and put it right back how it was)

@StormwaterGuru yep, it'll do that... so don't take this in any way as critical of your authoring skills; just advice for how you can approach troubleshooting.

@JoelCoehoorn much appreciated :)

Try this.

All conditions work together

where condition1 and condition2 and condition3


Condition is always true when textbox is empty.

Example (Updated)
SELECT Index.[Rec No], Index.[Type of Plan], Index.[Index Code], Index.Project, Index.Year, Index.Consultant, Index.[Needs Reassigned?], Index.[Label Needed], Index.[Scan Status], Index.Notes
FROM [Index]
WHERE (Index.[Rec No]=[Forms]![Edit Record]![Rec No] 
         or [Forms]![Edit Record]![Rec No] Is Null ) 
  and (Index.[Index Code] Like ("*" & [Forms]![Edit Record]![Index Code] & "*")
            or ([Forms]![Edit Record]![Index Code] Is Null ) 
  AND (Index.Project Like ("*" & [Forms]![Edit Record]![Project] & "*")
            or ([Forms]![Edit Record]![Project] Is Null) )
ORDER BY Index.[Rec No], Index.[Index Code];

There len([Forms]![Edit Record]![Project])=0 
[Forms]![Edit Record]![Project] Is Null - check if condition is empty (not specified).
This check may be data type specific.

I copy pasted this in and it only responds to the entry of the Rec No. Index Code and Project no longer work, they return no result.

Len(Null) = Null, so checking for =0 won't work. Use (... Is Null) instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38899574/3820271

Yes, for direct link from datasource query to form control, need use (... Is Null). Thank you.

As to your specification (which doesn't match your code) it should be:
WHERE 
    Index.[Rec No] = [Forms]![Edit Record]![Rec No] OR 
    Index.[Index Code] Like "*" & [Forms]![Edit Record]![Index Code] & "*" OR 
    Index.Project Like "*" & [Forms]![Edit Record]![Project] & "*"


Forgive me, I don't see what is different in this example? The only thing I could identify is that third condition was changed to OR. I had it that way originally, but it only worked on condition 2 or 3 by combining them into a conjoined or/and statement. When I went into design view to see why this worked, the only thing I could come up with is that by saying or/and for conditions 2 and 3, it was essentially saying OR, OR. That probably makes so sense. I'd add a picture if I could.

You specify three conditions, each valid: 1. or 2. or 3. That must be the starting point. Your code goes here and there, but what to know? If the specified conditions have changed, please update your question to refelct this in detail.
